# how do you get something to move on the z axis in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in unity trying to make a space shooter while watching the tutorial. The bolt is supposed to move on the z axis but it falls instead, and the ammo is not using gravity.

```
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

rb.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
```

what you see above is what the instructor told me to put into the script.

Comment: Have you importd the bolt object from another software? Your coordinates system might be messed up.

Comment: @Jonas giuro I imported it from unity3d.com

Comment: You can always take your rb object (prefab i'm assuming), and lock the x & y axis. You need to get the underlying cause of this anomaly though. Ensure that it's the z axis that it needs to travel on. In your editor window go to the top view and look at your axis, post a screenshot so we can see.

Comment: In the code you can also do rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX | |RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;

Comment: **you are suffering one of the most basic problems in game engineering.**  Models **must be built** with "z-forward".

Comment: here:  https://answers.unity.com/answers/433912/view.html

Comment: @Fattie There's no way of knowing that he's NOT done that, BTW. You're making assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

For the movement in the z axis, if the rotation of the bolt is zero in each of the vectors of the transform and it doesn't have a parent with any other non-zero rotation it should move in unity's z axis correctly with transform.forward. If that doesn't work then, instead of transform.forward you could use Vector3.up, or Vector3.forward instead.

Answer (score 0):

The forward vector is the blue one in Unity editor. Check that your bolt goes in the direction of the blue arrow. It it doesn't, check that you correctly disabled gravity in the rigidbody of this object (be sure it is the right one). In the same way, be sure that you added your script in on the right object.

If you still can't figure out what goes wrong, give us more precision. Does your projectile go in a straight line, or is it still affected by gravity? What happens if you change the speed value, doesn't it work?

This is likely a problem in the setup in Unity's editor. The script is fine so we can't really know more without seeing the editor